# SwiftUI - How to remove drag preview transparency

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag & drop using SwiftUI. The problem I'm facing is that drag preview view is transparent by default. How can I remove transparency?

Here is my code:

```
var body: some View {
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    LazyVGrid(columns: ...) {
        ForEach(...) { item in
            createItem(...)
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.didSelect(item)
                }
                .onDrag {
                    let haptic = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
                    haptic.prepare()
                    haptic.impactOccurred()
                    draggingItem = item
                    viewModel.didStartDragging(item)
                    return NSItemProvider(object: String(item.id) as NSString)
                } preview: {
                    makePreviewItem(...)
                }
                .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: DropRelocateDelegate(didFinishDragging: {
                    draggingItem = nil
                    viewModel.didFinishDragging()
                }))
        }
    }
    .frame(height: 100)
}
```

I've tried setting opacity to 1 (`.oacity(1)`) and setting background (`.background(Colors.someCustomColor)`) but without any luck.